# Why does deleted row appear after insertion instead of the new row?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom cell with Text Field. I do row deletion in a standard manner:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        dataArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellId", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCell

        myCell.textField.placeholder = dataArray[indexPath.row]

        return myCell
    }
```

Also I use my own class for the cell.

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    setupViews()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

let textField: UITextField = {
    var field = UITextField()
    field.placeholder = "Placeholder Text"
    field.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false   
    return field
}()

func setupViews() {
    addSubview(textField)

    //Constraints stuff
}
```

**The problem is** if Text Field contains a text and I delete that row, after insertion of a new row I get the old one with the text.

How can I avoid it? I need clean row.

BTW, animation doesn't work properly as well.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please show your cell for index path function.

Comment: you should call `tableView.beginUpdates()` before you delete the rows and call `tableView.endUpdates()` afterwards. It is also possible that in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you are reusing a cell, which has been deleted.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I've added cellForRowAtIndexPath code and my custom cell class code.

Comment: @kcpac Thank you. Will try and let you know whether it works or not.

Comment: @kcpac ...
        if editingStyle == .Delete {
            **tableView.beginUpdates()**
            timers.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Left)
            **tableView.endUpdates()**
        }
    }
Unfortunately it doesn't work. I am new in iOS and hope that I've added those lines in a correct place.

Comment: Problem solved! Thank to all of you, guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UITableViewCell`'s `prepareForReuse()` method.

```
func prepareForReuse() {
    textField.text = nil
}
```

More info [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse).

Answer (score 1):

Your cellForRowAtIndexPath is responsible for setting the correct values on any cell.  It is probably reusing the cell you just delete. Make sure that cellForRowAtIndexPath is resetting the values in your cell based on the indexPath whenever it is called (particularly after you deletion)

Comment: Thank you @Owen! After implementing @Mark's code I see that your answer is great too.